# How to receive data on click of notification in ios, when app is killed ,( react-native-fcm module to get push notification in IOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, react-native

I had designed the app using react native in both android and ios, and uses raact-native-fcm module for push notifications from server.
In android we send only data payload from server and it is received in onMessageReceived() weather the app is in foreground or minimised( background ) or killed,and then i can handle that data to show local notification which is doing fine.
But in IOS I don't know where the data payload is received in app, or 
if in case of IOS I send the notification payload along with/without data payload , i was able to receive notification, when app is in background or killed or notification data in FCM.on('notification',()=>{}); event when app is in foreground.
But when IOS app is killed i am not been able to handle the received notification, on click of notification app is opened but not able to get data or notification payload.
please help me out.

Comment: Ask your backend guy to put notification key in your payload.

Comment: if I provide notification payload from backend then, it gonna fine, i am able to receive notification( when app is in background(minimised or killed)), but on click of notification, app opens and i got my data in FCM.getInitialNotification().then(data=>{});
(react-native-fcm module).
But what i need is get data payload or notification payload in some function(weather app is in foreground or minimised or killed), where i can perform some task on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on push when app is killed, `didReceiveRemoteNotification` will not get called.

Push details will be available in `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    if (launchOptions!=nil) {
        NSMutableDictionary *userInfo = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
        NSLog(@"userInfo===%@", userInfo);
        if (userInfo.count>=1) {

            NSDictionary *apsInfo = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];
            NSLog(@"Received apsInfo Badge: %@", apsInfo);

            // now do what you have in push...
```

Comment: How to awake the killed IOS app via push so that I can fetch some data from the server? I am using react-native-firebase for push